# How to hard reset a Galaxy Tab S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, hard-reset

I cannot login to my Samsung Galaxy Tab S anymore and want to perform a hard reset. Googling the question yields to many answers which follow the scheme:

- when switched off press `Home` + `Volume Up` + `Power`
- when the Android system recovery menu appears scroll down to wipe

The problem I have is that after pressing `Home` + `Volume Up` + `Power` I get a different screen:

[image]

When choosing `Volume Up` I get to the `ODIN` download screen.

**How can I hard reset my tab in such a case?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get into recovery mode for this Samsung device. The correct button combination to push is

> Power button + Home button + volume Down button at the same time

The same combination but with volume up instead. Will take you into Odin/Download mode.